# What is a word (an adjective or a noun) saying a person who loves eating yummy food, shopping and can not live a simple life?

Tags: word-request

There is a person. If you give him food that is not delicious, then he will get angry. He also likes shopping and spends money on things that help him live comfortably.

He can not control his appetites for food and comfortable things even though he doesn't have much money. He can not live a simple life.

**What is a word (an adjective or a noun) saying a person who loves eating yummy food, shopping and can not live a simple life?**

Comment: Note that 'yummy' is not a formal word, and is mainly used when talking to small children.

Comment: This isn't a very coherent description. A person who loves eating "yummy" food sounds to me like someone who just likes stuffing their face with cheap sugar / fat / salty snacks (not a "gourmet", who likes ***fine*** food). But probably the most "accurate" words for someone who constantly seeks short-term sensory gratification are words like ***childish, infantile.*** Child psychologists established long ago that almost all children below about 5 choose to have 1 marshmallow sweet immediately, but children over 6 normally take the better option of two sweets if they just wait a few minutes.

Comment: When it comes to eating there is a hierarchy of sorts, glutton, gourmand
, gourmet. A glutton has always meant someone who eats to excess as did gourmand in the past, but today it is closer to gourmet, someone who appreciates fine dining.

Comment: Is there a word like that in your native language? What does it translate to in dictionaries? Does the meaning require that they spend money on good food, or is it about generally spending money on good things?

Comment: @PeterJennings - when I go to France, I sometimes visit a chain of cafeteria-style low-cost restaurants called Flunch, whose selling propositions are low price but high quality. They used to always have one item on each day's menu that was unlimited (you could go back for more as many times as you wanted), and their slogan was _Flunch, ou les gourmands rencontrent les gourmets_

Answer (score 3):

A **hedonist** is someone who believes that the pursuit of pleasure is the most important thing in life .

A **gourmand** is someone who enjoys eating (and so often eats to excess)

An **epicure** is someone who is devoted to sensual pleasure, especially that derived from food.

A **spendthrift** is someone who spends money in an extravagant, irresponsible way.

(definitions from Oxford)

Comment: Do you have a simpler word?

Comment: @Tom You might have to explain what you mean by "simpler".

Comment: No,  these are not everyday words, but I would expect most adults to have these words, at least in their passive vocabulary. "Hedonist" or "spendthrift" are about as simple as you are likely to find for this sense or meaning.

Comment: imho a ***gourmand*** is a greedy pig, whereas a ***gourmet*** is someone who appreciates *high quality* food. But they both really like eating.